# Parse file contains SQL queries with Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

There is issue with Java Regex.

File contains some SQL queries in the following format:

```
query_name_1 {
  any single line or multi line sql query
}

query_name_2 {
  any single line or multi line sql query
}

...

query_name_n {
  any single line or multi line sql query
}
```

Query name can contain only  uppercase and lower letters , number and underscore. SQL query must be inside curly bracket and should not be parsed for validation. Brackets must be on same line with query name or lower. Queries must be splitted with any space symbol.

I tried to use regex placed below but had no success.

```
[a-zA-Z_]+(\s*|\n*)\{.*\}
```

Please post any suggestion how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you missed in your queryname the usage of digits, therefore not

```
[a-zA-Z_]
```

but

```
[a-zA-Z_0-9]
```

Additional I included a group for the queryname and a group for the query itself and corrected some linefeed placements. So this is a regexp you could use:

```
    ([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\s*\{\n*((?:.|\n)+?)\}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wFtkAWbA7ECaK6RB)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regexp

```
Pattern.compile("query_name_[0-9]+.*?\{.*?\}",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This combines greedy matching and the fact that this way the . will match new characters also